# Remove tag from database

Tags: php, mysql, tags

If I have a tag system like Stackoverflow. I can add tags, save and after delete a tag, or add new tags.

For example, initially:

```
PHP, JQUERY, ARRAYS
```

save question and publish,

I changed my mind, and I will delete JQUERY, so I edited my question to only two tags:

```
PHP, ARRAYS
```

My question is: what is the best way to remove the tag from database after inserted?
I need to check which tag is removed.

Any idea? Thanks!

**To clarify the problem:**

i have a many- to -many table

```
$first = array (php, jquery, arrays)

question1 | php
question1 | jquery
question1 | arrays
```

after edited, i will have (the goal):

```
$first = array (php, jquery)

question1 | php
question1 | jquery
```

to add new tags is easy. Unique constrain, and a foreach solves the problem.
But to remove tags. I need to remove the specific **tag arrays** from the junction table.

the question is how ?

so, i have this array:  `$first = array (php, jquery)`

and this table structure (**THIS IS THE PROBLEM**):

```
question1 | php
question1 | jquery
question1 | arrays
```

Comment: You can get the tags with `$tags = array_map('trim', explode(',', $input));` or `$tags = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $input);`.

Comment: to clarify: the problem is not about tables or databases design. Is about remove tags from an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is best implemented as a *many-to-many* relationship.

You do this by using a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). For example

```
QUESTION
========
id, -- primary key
whatever

TAG
===
id, -- primary key
tag -- probably best with UNIQUE constraint

QUESTION_TAG
============
question_id, -- composite primary key, foreign key references QUESTION (id)
tag_id -- composite primary key, foreign key references TAG (id)
```

To remove a tag for a question, simply delete the record from the `QUESTION_TAG` table, eg

```
DELETE FROM `QUESTION_TAG`
WHERE `question_id` = :question_id
AND `tag_id` = :tag_id
```

### Update

Your best bet is to make tag removal a capture-able event. What I mean by this is that each removal is handled in a way so you are able to capture the tag to be removed.

Another approach is to remove all `QUESTION_TAG` entries for the question and re-insert the tags to keep.

Comment: When properly indexed, this makes for a very robust tagging system where you can query tags per thing, and things per tag very easily.

Comment: but you use a foreach ? an array, and check what value are removed ? the problem is that

Comment: @Daniel You would need to know the question and tag ids before executing the delete query but retrieving these should be trivial. If you set a unique constraint on `TAG.tag`, you can even find a tag by its text representation

Comment: thanks, i will use the second approach. remove all tags and insert again.